# In Flask ignore all webhooks but one

Tags: python, flask, webhooks

I have a python script with flask incorporated running on a RaspberryPi. This is set to trigger a wakeonlan script when IFTTT sends the appropriate POST webhook. Since I've turned it on I've been getting a LOT of random webhooks from random IPs. Obviously, they all get a 404 error as nothing else is active, but it still concerns me a bit.

Is there a way to make flask ignore (just completely not respond) to any webhooks that aren't the specific one (a POST to /post) I'm looking for? I've tried screwing with the return line, but then flask throws an error saying "View function did not return a response" and returns an error 500.

Is this even possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from flask import Flask, request
from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
dt = datetime.now()

print("WakeOnLan started at: ", dt)

@app.route('/post', methods= ["POST"])

def post():
        print("POST received at: ", dt)
        body = request.get_data(as_text=True)
        if body == "desktop":
                send_magic_packet('XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.XX')
                print("Magic Packet sent to", body, "at:", dt)
                return ''

#Router forwards port 80 to 30000 on the pi
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = 30000)
```

Comment: How about catching all non-POST request to /post using a custom function with the function not doing anything like only a pass statement?

Comment: My goal is to send no response at all so that to the sending side, it looks like there is nothing there. A lot of the requests being sent are just webcrawlers looking for favicon.ico or robot.txt and stuff like that, but some of them are coming from IPs in sketchy parts of the world that I'd like to just look invisible to.